# How to retrieve specific elements from an object into different arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have this allData array with objects in it. I need to store the 'data' object into either the customers, addresses or stores array based on the type of key each element is inside allData. This is what I have so far. But when I run it, it still states that the arrays have no values.

```
var allData = [
        {type:"store", data:{store_id: 297, name: "Scotiabank - Main Branch", address_id: 1023}},
        {type:"store", data:{store_id: 614, name: "Scotiabank - Hamilton", address_id: 1984}},
        {type:"store", data:{store_id: 193, name: "Scotiabank - Mississauga", address_id: 1757}},
        {type:"customer", data:{customer_id: 26, store_id:297, first_name: "Dave", last_name: "Bennett", email: "dbennett@gmail.com", address_id: 4536, add_date: null}},
        {type:"customer", data:{customer_id: 59, store_id:193, first_name: "John", last_name: "Stevens", email: "jstevens22@hotmail.com", address_id: 2473, add_date: null}},
        {type:"customer", data:{customer_id: 29, store_id:614, first_name: "Sarah", last_name: "Pym", email: "spym99@hotmail.com", address_id: 1611, add_date: null}},
        {type:"customer", data:{customer_id: 63, store_id:297, first_name: "Steven", last_name: "Edwards", email: "steven2231@hotmail.com", address_id: 1836, add_date: null}},
        {type:"customer", data:{customer_id: 71, store_id:614, first_name: "Martin", last_name: "Scott", email: "mdog33@gmail.com", address_id: 2727, add_date: null}},
        {type:"customer", data:{customer_id: 24, store_id:614, first_name: "Jonathan", last_name: "Pym", email: "jjpym@yahoo.ca", address_id: 1611, add_date: null}},
        {type:"customer", data:{customer_id: 36, store_id:193, first_name: "Kaitlyn", last_name: "Adams", email: "katy38@hotmail.com", address_id: 5464, add_date: null}},
        {type:"customer", data:{customer_id: 73, store_id:297, first_name: "Melissa", last_name: "Bennett", email: "mbennett@gmail.com", address_id: 4536, add_date: null}},         
        {type:"address", data:{address_id: 1023, address: "2895 Yonge St.", city:"Toronto", province:"ON", postal_code:"L4C02G"}},
        {type:"address", data:{address_id: 1984, address: "3611 Main St. West", city:"Hamilton", province:"ON", postal_code:"R5O8H5"}},
        {type:"address", data:{address_id: 1757, address: "1177 Ontario St. Unit 8", city:"Mississauga", province:"ON", postal_code:"L9H6B3"}},
        {type:"address", data:{address_id: 4536, address: "3945 John St.", city: "Ajax", province: "ON", postal_code: "L7M4T9"}},
        {type:"address", data:{address_id: 2473, address: "391 Baker St. Apt 231", city: "Mississauga", province: "ON", postal_code: "M4T8S3"}},
        {type:"address", data:{address_id: 1611, address: "183 City Ct.", city: "Hamilton", province: "ON", postal_code: "J3T9V2"}},
        {type:"address", data:{address_id: 1836, address: "67 Rhymer Ave.", city: "Stouffville", province: "ON", postal_code: "L3C8H4"}},
        {type:"address", data:{address_id: 2727, address: "287 Brant St. Apt 4A", city: "Waterdown", province: "ON", postal_code: "R93G3P"}},
        {type:"address", data:{address_id: 5464, address: "11 New St. Apt 2B", city: "Brampton", province: "ON", postal_code: "L694R7"}},
    ];
    
    var CustomerDB = {
      customers:[],
       addresses:[],
       stores:[],
      insertData:function(allData){
        for (let i = 0; i<allData.length;i++){
          if (allData.type[i] == "store"){
            stores.push(allData[i].data);
            
          }
          if (allData.type[i] == "customer"){
            customers.push(allData[i].data);
          }
          if (allData.type[i] == "address"){
            customers.push(allData[i].data);
          }
        }
        
      }
     
    };
```

Comment: try `allData[i].type` instead? `type` doesn't seem to be an array or object

Answer (score 0):

```js
var allData = [
    {type:"store", data:{store_id: 297, name: "Scotiabank - Main Branch", address_id: 1023}},
    {type:"store", data:{store_id: 614, name: "Scotiabank - Hamilton", address_id: 1984}},
    {type:"store", data:{store_id: 193, name: "Scotiabank - Mississauga", address_id: 1757}},
    {type:"customer", data:{customer_id: 26, store_id:297, first_name: "Dave", last_name: "Bennett", email: "dbennett@gmail.com", address_id: 4536, add_date: null}},
    {type:"customer", data:{customer_id: 59, store_id:193, first_name: "John", last_name: "Stevens", email: "jstevens22@hotmail.com", address_id: 2473, add_date: null}},
    {type:"customer", data:{customer_id: 29, store_id:614, first_name: "Sarah", last_name: "Pym", email: "spym99@hotmail.com", address_id: 1611, add_date: null}},
    {type:"customer", data:{customer_id: 63, store_id:297, first_name: "Steven", last_name: "Edwards", email: "steven2231@hotmail.com", address_id: 1836, add_date: null}},
    {type:"customer", data:{customer_id: 71, store_id:614, first_name: "Martin", last_name: "Scott", email: "mdog33@gmail.com", address_id: 2727, add_date: null}},
    {type:"customer", data:{customer_id: 24, store_id:614, first_name: "Jonathan", last_name: "Pym", email: "jjpym@yahoo.ca", address_id: 1611, add_date: null}},
    {type:"customer", data:{customer_id: 36, store_id:193, first_name: "Kaitlyn", last_name: "Adams", email: "katy38@hotmail.com", address_id: 5464, add_date: null}},
    {type:"customer", data:{customer_id: 73, store_id:297, first_name: "Melissa", last_name: "Bennett", email: "mbennett@gmail.com", address_id: 4536, add_date: null}},
    {type:"address", data:{address_id: 1023, address: "2895 Yonge St.", city:"Toronto", province:"ON", postal_code:"L4C02G"}},
    {type:"address", data:{address_id: 1984, address: "3611 Main St. West", city:"Hamilton", province:"ON", postal_code:"R5O8H5"}},
    {type:"address", data:{address_id: 1757, address: "1177 Ontario St. Unit 8", city:"Mississauga", province:"ON", postal_code:"L9H6B3"}},
    {type:"address", data:{address_id: 4536, address: "3945 John St.", city: "Ajax", province: "ON", postal_code: "L7M4T9"}},
    {type:"address", data:{address_id: 2473, address: "391 Baker St. Apt 231", city: "Mississauga", province: "ON", postal_code: "M4T8S3"}},
    {type:"address", data:{address_id: 1611, address: "183 City Ct.", city: "Hamilton", province: "ON", postal_code: "J3T9V2"}},
    {type:"address", data:{address_id: 1836, address: "67 Rhymer Ave.", city: "Stouffville", province: "ON", postal_code: "L3C8H4"}},
    {type:"address", data:{address_id: 2727, address: "287 Brant St. Apt 4A", city: "Waterdown", province: "ON", postal_code: "R93G3P"}},
    {type:"address", data:{address_id: 5464, address: "11 New St. Apt 2B", city: "Brampton", province: "ON", postal_code: "L694R7"}},
];
    
var CustomerDB = {
    customers: [],
    addresses: [],
    stores: [],
    insertData: function (allData) {    //it is not necessary to add function, over here... You can try "Object.setPrototypeOf(CustomerDB, {insertData: function (allData) {}});" this after defining CustomerDB;
        this.customers = [];
        this.addresses = [];
        this.stores = [];

        for (let i = 0; i < allData.length; i++) {
            if (allData[i].type == "store") {
                this.stores.push(allData[i].data);
            }
            if (allData[i].type == "customer") {
                this.customers.push(allData[i].data);
            }
            if (allData[i].type == "address") {
                this.customers.push(allData[i].data);
            }
        }
    }
}
    
CustomerDB.insertData(allData);
console.log(CustomerDB);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change `allData.type[i]` to `allData[i].type` within your loop. Since `allData.type[i]` will check if the object in the current iteration has a property named `type`, which also has the current iteration as a property. Basically, this is what you're evaluating:

`allData.type['{type:"store", data:{store_id: 297, name: "Scotiabank - Main Branch", address_id: 1023}}'] == 'theValue'`

Solution:

```js
var allData = [
    {type:"store", data:{store_id: 297, name: "Scotiabank - Main Branch", address_id: 1023}},
    {type:"store", data:{store_id: 614, name: "Scotiabank - Hamilton", address_id: 1984}},
    {type:"store", data:{store_id: 193, name: "Scotiabank - Mississauga", address_id: 1757}},
    {type:"customer", data:{customer_id: 26, store_id:297, first_name: "Dave", last_name: "Bennett", email: "dbennett@gmail.com", address_id: 4536, add_date: null}},
    {type:"customer", data:{customer_id: 59, store_id:193, first_name: "John", last_name: "Stevens", email: "jstevens22@hotmail.com", address_id: 2473, add_date: null}},
    {type:"customer", data:{customer_id: 29, store_id:614, first_name: "Sarah", last_name: "Pym", email: "spym99@hotmail.com", address_id: 1611, add_date: null}},
    {type:"customer", data:{customer_id: 63, store_id:297, first_name: "Steven", last_name: "Edwards", email: "steven2231@hotmail.com", address_id: 1836, add_date: null}},
    {type:"customer", data:{customer_id: 71, store_id:614, first_name: "Martin", last_name: "Scott", email: "mdog33@gmail.com", address_id: 2727, add_date: null}},
    {type:"customer", data:{customer_id: 24, store_id:614, first_name: "Jonathan", last_name: "Pym", email: "jjpym@yahoo.ca", address_id: 1611, add_date: null}},
    {type:"customer", data:{customer_id: 36, store_id:193, first_name: "Kaitlyn", last_name: "Adams", email: "katy38@hotmail.com", address_id: 5464, add_date: null}},
    {type:"customer", data:{customer_id: 73, store_id:297, first_name: "Melissa", last_name: "Bennett", email: "mbennett@gmail.com", address_id: 4536, add_date: null}},         
    {type:"address", data:{address_id: 1023, address: "2895 Yonge St.", city:"Toronto", province:"ON", postal_code:"L4C02G"}},
    {type:"address", data:{address_id: 1984, address: "3611 Main St. West", city:"Hamilton", province:"ON", postal_code:"R5O8H5"}},
    {type:"address", data:{address_id: 1757, address: "1177 Ontario St. Unit 8", city:"Mississauga", province:"ON", postal_code:"L9H6B3"}},
    {type:"address", data:{address_id: 4536, address: "3945 John St.", city: "Ajax", province: "ON", postal_code: "L7M4T9"}},
    {type:"address", data:{address_id: 2473, address: "391 Baker St. Apt 231", city: "Mississauga", province: "ON", postal_code: "M4T8S3"}},
    {type:"address", data:{address_id: 1611, address: "183 City Ct.", city: "Hamilton", province: "ON", postal_code: "J3T9V2"}},
    {type:"address", data:{address_id: 1836, address: "67 Rhymer Ave.", city: "Stouffville", province: "ON", postal_code: "L3C8H4"}},
    {type:"address", data:{address_id: 2727, address: "287 Brant St. Apt 4A", city: "Waterdown", province: "ON", postal_code: "R93G3P"}},
    {type:"address", data:{address_id: 5464, address: "11 New St. Apt 2B", city: "Brampton", province: "ON", postal_code: "L694R7"}},
];
        
var CustomerDB = {
  customers:[],
  addresses:[],
  stores:[],
  insertData(allData) {
    allData.forEach(obj => {
      if(obj.type === 'store') {
        this.stores.push(obj.data);
      }
      else if(obj.type === 'customer') {
        this.customers.push(obj.data);
      }
      else if (obj.type === 'address') {
        this.addresses.push(obj.data);
      } else {
        // Anything you want to do with an object that has a 
        // different type 
      }
    }); 
  }
};

  CustomerDB.insertData(allData);
  console.log(CustomerDB.customers);
  console.log(CustomerDB.stores);
  console.log(CustomerDB.addresses);
```